# i have converted array data to .html file but now want to append html data using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert the array data into HTML format and want to save the file as a .html file. How can I do this?

Suppose the array is:

```
Array
(
[0-50] => 880
[50-100] => 5
[100-150] => 1
[550-600] => 1
)
```

And I am writting a file like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("abc.html","w");
?>
```

I can write this file as a CSV format easily but how can I do this to store a html file from data?

my expected result is -

```
Distance      trips
 0-50          880
 50-100         5
 100-150        1
 550-600        1
```

distance and trips here are the table header and in distance field all are the keys of the array and in trips all are the values of the array.

Suppose i have written the data into this file ->

```
$html['head'] = '<html><head></head><body>';

$html['content'] = "<table><tr style='background-color:cyan'><td>Distance</td><td>total Trips</td></tr>";

foreach($de as $key=>$value)
 {

$html['content'] .="<tr style='background-color:yellow'><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";

 }
 $html['foot'] = '</table></body>';

file_put_contents("abc.html", $html);
```

Now i wanted to append this file with this data ->

```
$html['head'] = '<html><head></head><body>';

$html['content'] = "<h2>Data Regarding 0 - 50 km distance</h2>
<table width=900 border=5>
<tr style='background-color:cyan font-size:24px'>
<td>S.No</td>
<td>Customer Id</td>
<td>Total Distance</td>
<td>Total Trips</td>
<td>Average Speed</td>
";

foreach($dec as $result=>$value) {

$html['content'] .= "<tr style='background-color:lightgreen'><td>$value[cid]</td><td>$value[totalDistance]</td><td>$value[totalTrips]</td><td>$value[avgSpeed]</td></tr>";
}    
$html['foot'] = '</table></body></html>';
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: try fputs method http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you place dynamic information in static HTML document, you need to rewrite this information on each edit.

1. Use some PHP library to read HTML file (like [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/))
2. Gather all table information from HTML file.
3. Append new information (or insert where needed).
4. Write new content to HTML file.

I suggest to save this information to some structured format (like json file or database) and when showing information, just read this data. It would be much easier to implement.

E.g. rewriting data in json file:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
$json = array_merge($json, $newData);
file_put_contents(json_encode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first table you want to put in a html file, this will do the work using your methodology  :

```
<?php 

//Creating the array
$de = Array("0-50" => 880,
"50-100" => 5,
"100-150" => 1,
"550-600" => 1
);

//creating the array corresponding to html code
$html = array();

//Creating the header
$html['head'] = '<html><head></head><body>';

//creating content - table header
$html['content'] = "<table><tr style='background-color:cyan'><td>Distance</td><td>total Trips</td></tr>";

foreach($de as $key=>$value)
{
    $html['content'] .="<tr style='background-color:yellow'><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
}

//footer
$html['foot'] = '</table></body>';

//no need to use fopen because file_put_contents manages that.
file_put_contents("abc.html", $html);

?>
```

But for the second part of your question, the same logic will work, just be careful how you use array, specially here :

```
foreach($dec as $result=>$value)
{
    $html['content'] .= "<tr style='background-color:lightgreen'><td>$value[cid]</td><td>$value[totalDistance]</td><td>$value[totalTrips]</td><td>$value[avgSpeed]</td></tr>";
}
```

You should write it this way :

```
foreach($dec as $result=>$value) 
{
    $html['content'] .= "<tr style='background-color:lightgreen'><td>".$value['cid']."</td><td>".$value['totalDistance']."</td><td>".$value['totalTrips']."</td><td>".$value['avgSpeed']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Hi hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Append Mode.

`a => Open for writing only;`

Or

`a+ => Open for reading and writing;`

What this mode does is "*place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.*"

So your fopen line becomes ...

```
$file = fopen("abc.html","a");
```

This ways you can always append whatever you want.